Positioning an input button and overriding SVG
If you make the beginning coordinates and ending coordinates of the Bezier curve equidistant, then you can duplicate Bezier curves.
If you click the button, a second Bezier curve will appear under the first one.  The second Bezier curve will be the same size as the first.  And because they are the same size, the two Bezier curves will form a perfect circle.
No matter what I try to do, my Bezier Curve seems to push my button to the bottom of my screen.  I've tried to use CSS and even the Javascript setAttribute to fix this problem, but nothing seems to work. How do I display my XHTML button so that it will be above the SVG Bezier curve?  Here is my HTML code:
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>SVG_Bezier_Curve</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.css"/>
      <script language="javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve_2.js">
      
      </script>
</head>
<body onload = "Setup()">
     <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" onclick="Setup2()" value="Click Me!" position = "absolute" top = "100px"/>
     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="My_SVG" position = "absolute" top = "200px" height="500px" width="600px">
     <path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
     <path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
     </svg>
</body>

Here is my Javascript code:
    function Setup() {
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    var Attribute_Name;
    var Attribute_Name_2;
    var Coordinate;
    var My_Properties;
    var Button_Identification;
    
    
    
    Attribute_Name = "d";
    Attribute_Name_2 = "style";
    My_Properties = "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3; fill: none;";
    Coordinate = "M 375 200 A 50 50 0 0 1 475 200";
    Button_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_Button');
    Button_Identification.setAttribute = ("style", "top: 100px; height: 200px;");
    Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name, Coordinate);
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name_2, My_Properties);
    
    
  
}

function Setup2() {
    
    var SVG_Data;
    var Retrieved_Data;
    var Bezier_Curve_1;
    var Bezier_Curve_2;
    var Counter;
    var Coordinate_Attribute;
    var Coordinate;
    var Style_Attribute;
    var Style_Details;
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    
    SVG_Data = new XMLHttpRequest();
          SVG_Data.open("GET","http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/apps/HTML_Student/SVG_Bezier_Curve.xq", true);
          SVG_Data.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (SVG_Data.readyState == 4) {
              Retrieved_Data = SVG_Data.responseText;
              Retrieved_Data = Retrieved_Data.split("/");
              Counter = 0;
              Bezier_Curve_1 = Retrieved_Data[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Bezier_Curve_2 = Retrieved_Data[Counter];}
              Bezier_Curve_1 = Bezier_Curve_1.split("*");
              Counter = 0;
              Coordinate_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Coordinate = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Details = Bezier_Curve_1[Counter];
              Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Coordinate_Attribute, Coordinate);
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Style_Attribute, Style_Details);
              Bezier_Curve_2 = Bezier_Curve_2.split("*");
              Counter = 0;
              Coordinate_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Coordinate = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Attribute = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Counter = Counter + 1;
              Style_Details = Bezier_Curve_2[Counter];
              Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_2');
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Coordinate_Attribute, Coordinate);
              Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Style_Attribute, Style_Details);
              
              };

SVG_Data.send();}

And here is my CSS code:
 #Bezier_Curve_Button {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 50px;
height: 100px;
width: 150px;}


Why are you positioning the input and the SVG? Just remove all that and use a flexbox column layout.

Please take the time to get familiar with StackOverflow Snippets to provide a minimal reproducible example. Obviously, we can't access all these localhost URLs. position and  top are CSS properties and no valid SVG presentation attributes. Quite likely, you're facing a simple CSS/SVG viewBox related issue. Keep in mind SVG has no "content-fit" capabilities to adjust the viewBox to its content. So please try to reduce your example to the bare minimum.

It has been several years since I coded webpages.  The last webpage I coded was in 2018.  At that time I was still using version 2 of the eXist database.  I work in retail and I was slammed with hours for several years.  So I became a rip van winkle until things eased up this year.  So I didn't know that this flexbox existed.  I will have to research this topic further.  But are you saying that the CSS position absolute command no longer works?

Absolute positioning is a very poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out LearnLayout.com

There are multiple syntax errors in your code.
Firstly, elements such as <input> and <svg> do not have position or top attributes. All these declarations belong in CSS.
The adjustments you're attempting to make in script aren't right either. This line is wrong:
Button_Identification.setAttribute = ("style", "top: 100px; height: 200px;");

Instead, it should be:
Button_Identification.style = "top: 100px; height: 200px;";

Here is a runnable snippet which fixes these problems, perhaps it may give you some help in getting where you need to go.


function Setup() {
    var Bezier_Curve_Identification;
    var Attribute_Name;
    var Attribute_Name_2;
    var Coordinate;
    var My_Properties;
    var Button_Identification;
    
    Attribute_Name = "d";
    Attribute_Name_2 = "style";
    My_Properties = "stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3; fill: none;";
    Coordinate = "M 375 200 A 50 50 0 0 1 475 200";
    Button_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_Button');
    Button_Identification.style = "top: 100px; height: 200px;";
    Bezier_Curve_Identification = document.getElementById('Bezier_Curve_1');
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name, Coordinate);
    Bezier_Curve_Identification.setAttribute(Attribute_Name_2, My_Properties);
}

Setup()
#Bezier_Curve_Button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#My_SVG {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
<body>
  <input type="button" id="Bezier_Curve_Button" value="Click Me!"/>
  <svg id="My_SVG">
    <path id="Bezier_Curve_1"/>
    <path id="Bezier_Curve_2"/>
  </svg>
</body>



We could, of course, help you get closer to where you need to go, but in your post you didn't provide a clear description of what the end result should look like, nor did you illustrate it, nor did you explain what should happen when you press the button. If you need further help it would be great idea to edit your post to improve it.
